# Animated movie: boy finds a time machine, finds tribe of people who were being "sucked in" into the ground

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I saw this movie years ago, so I only remember it vaguely. A boy finds a time machine (or something similar) and he is (probably) taken to the past. He finds a tribe, they had a major problem - people were being "sucked in" into the ground (through the sand if I recall correctly) so people started disappearing rapidly (not sure if they know that they were being "sucked in" or they just noticed the disappearances). Also I think that they were actually pulled down by someone down below.

Comment: When was "years ago?"

Comment: I don't remember, more than 7 years for sure, maybe even 10 xd

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: We have this one. It's based off of the Time Machine novels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 2002 film *[Time Kid](https://timemachine.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Kid)*

> In 19th Century New Jersey, a young boy named Tom Spender discovers his missing father's Time Machine with a note in the seat, saying that the father was stuck in the future and unable to return home. Tom boards the machine and explores the future, first visiting the year 2002 where he meets one of his descendants, and later the year 11,902.
>
> There, he meets a strange race of people- the Luman, who are a very simple, almost childlike folk who live in a domed community. They also have telekinetic powers. When Tom wonders where the food comes from, he discovers that it is provided by a second race, the Sub-Men. When the Luman come to get their food, the Sub-Men take a Luman in exchange.
>
> It seems that the Sub-Men are using electrical energy from the Luman's telekinetic powers to run their machines. Tom soon befriends a Sub-Man, Zorog, and convinces him that there are better ways for the two races to exist. The two soon rescue Lira, who has been captured, as well as Spender's father, Henry Spender.

Previously the answer to [Old cartoon movie about a time traveling boy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163626/old-cartoon-movie-about-a-time-traveling-boy)

The review [here](http://aminoapps.com/page/cartoon/9981410/time-kid-worst-movie-ever) mentions people being sucked into the ground:

> Tom goes with the group and watches them hold hands and circle a table covered in bread.
>
> Something grabs one of the boys and he is dragged under the sand as everyone grabs the food and pretends nothing is happening.
>
> Tom digs in the sand and finds a manhole, going down it to find the Submen have been feeding the Lumen in exchange for one of them each time to power their machines.

### Teaser